# How can I get GPIO working on the Orange Pi Zero Plus (v1)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux, debian

When running the pyA20 library in python I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyA20.gpio.port' has no attribute 'PA0'
```

Or when running gpio readall I get the error:

```
Oops: Unable to determine board revision from /proc/cpuinfo
 -> No "Hardware" line
 ->  You'd best google the error to find out why.
```

Ive tried editing /proc/cpuinfo to make it the same as a standard Orange Pi zero but it wont allow me to save

Please note Im using Orange Pi Zero **PLUS**

Comment: Are you using the updated version of the library with support for the H5 instead of just the A20?  https://github.com/herzig/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH5

Comment: Thanks, thats sorted it, If you add this as an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different versions of this library for different processors.  The A20 version will not work correctly on an H3 or H5 processor.

You can download the correct version for the A5 [here](https://github.com/herzig/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH5)